# How to convert/create a valid JSON to send to a web service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to send a JSON to my web service that looks like that:

```
{
 "title": "Editorial updated",
 "id": "d4ef0cfe-0b7b-4432-a099-75a221c2258b",
 "articleAuthors":[
        {
            "AuthorId":"9f154e53-bf06-439e-9253-69d33081c064"
        },
        {
            "AuthorId":"6f10c8ad-52d6-4dfd-a223-eec1cb635881"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I send this request using Postman, it works well.

The problem occurs when I want to send the same content from my Angular component, specifically the *articleAuthors* part. Here is how I constructed it.

```
const authorsSelected = this.form.value.authors;
const authorsSelectedArray : {}[] = [];
authorsSelected.forEach(function (value) {
  const articleAuthorObj = {} as ArticleAuthorTest;
  articleAuthorObj.authorId = value;
  authorsSelectedArray.push(articleAuthorObj);
});
this.form.value.articleAuthors = authorsSelectedArray;
```

In Chrome Dev Tools, the JSON looks like that

[image]

When I try to send this to the server, I keep stucked with an error 500. I don't any difference between the JSON created with Postman and the one created on Angular.

As requested in comments, here is a screenshot of what is sent in 'Network' Tab

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you think is wrong? I don't see any difference with the `articleAuthors` list, but the casing of `title` is different in the 2 examples

Comment: Sorry for the Typo, it works with Title or title. The problem is only with articleAuthors, I just want to send a valid JSON but the server doesn't accept it

Comment: the thing is you are constructing your data well.

Comment: What are you actually sending to the server? Can you check the network tab in Chrome DevTools and see what's being shipped?

Answer (score 0):

```
articleAuthorObj.AuthorId = value;
```

you can keep casing consistent.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: If you have access to server logs you can recheck what exception is there, usually 500: Internal server error is by mismatch of data parameters but sometimes other security exceptions are also there.

Comment: I don't get any error in Backend side. And the same JSON using Postman is working well

Comment: are you using .net as backend ? if yes then double-check content-type in request and backend controller. As visible request content-type is application/json-patch json in postman it is usually application/json